# matplotlib stacked bar chart with zero centerd

Tags: matplotlib

I have a dataset like below.

| T/F | Value | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T | 1 | A |
| F | 3 | B |
| T | 5 | C |
| F | 7 | A |
| T | 8 | B |
| ... | ... | ... |

so, I want to draw a bar chart like below. same categoy has same position

same category has same position, zero centered bar and number of F is bar below the horizontal line, T is upper bar.
[image]

How can I make this chart with matplotlib.pyplot? or other library

I need example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach involves making the `False` values negative, and then creating a Seaborn `barplot` with `T/F` as hue. You might want to make a copy of the data if you can't change the original.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'T/F': ['T', 'F', 'T', 'F', 'T'],
                     'Value': [1, 3, 5, 7, 8],
                     'category': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B']})
data['Value'] = np.where(data['T/F'] == 'T', data['Value'], -data['Value'])
ax = sns.barplot(data=data, x='category', y='Value', hue='T/F', dodge=False, palette='turbo')
ax.axhline(0, lw=2, color='black')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.barplot joining positives and negatives]